# How to forbidden using object to static member function

Tags: c++, static

I have a simple class, and a static member function:

```
class Matrix
{
public: 
    static Matrix returnSomething ( Matrix &m )
    {
        return Matrix(2,2);
    }
};
```

main function:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix matrix(2,2);                           // some matrix
    Matrix m = Matrix::returnSomething ( matrix ) // I should use it that way
    m.print() // it shows the matrix       

    // but I can use it too that way //

    Matrix m;
    m.returnSomething ( matrix )                  // how to make this not allowed??
    m.print() // but here the matrix is NULL, wont show anything 
}
```

How to do it?

Edit:

I have added some print function that shows the problem

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Because when I forgot one time, and I use m.returnSomething instead of Matrix::returnSomething, it won't work

Comment: What do you mean it won't work? Why wouldn't it work? It's exactly the same thing.

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps you could provide some code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: yes maybe, but when I use m.returnSomething() the return value will disappear... or I have something wrong with my code...

Comment: Definitely something else wrong with the code. I suggest you investigate that.

Comment: I edited the code for better understand this problem ;)

Comment: Your problem is not that you are calling a static member function on an instance, it is that in one case you assign the result to `m` and in the other you don't.

Comment: I dont know if you understand me, when I do m.returnSomething() the m object would be still the same because return matrix is nowhere saved. Maybe that I am bad at english, sorry for that

Comment: @juanchopanza I know that, and I want to protect it from myself ;)

Comment: in case you want to call m.returnSomething() that way, why don't you make `returnSomething` a member function?

Comment: You can't. It is like saying `int i = 0`, `int y = i + 1` and expecting `i` to be `42`.

Comment: @10WaRRioR01 The problem is that I want not to use `m.returnSomething`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a helper class?

```
class MatrixHelper
{
public: 
    static Matrix returnSomething ( Matrix &m )
    {
        return Matrix(2,2);
    }
};
```

Then the invocation would be:

```
MatrixHelper::returnSomething ( matrix )
```

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't make a difference.  However, you can use a namespace instead of static functions

```
namespace MatrixUtils
{
  Matrix returnSomething ( Matrix &m )
  {
     return Matrix(2,2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing two issues. The return value "disappears" because you don't assign it to anything - this has no relation to how you invoke the function.

In other words, these will both work:

```
Matrix matrix(2, 2);
Matrix m = Matrix::returnSomething(matrix);
Matrix m2 = m.returnSomething(martix);
```

While these will both make the return value "disappear:"

```
Matrix matrix(2, 2);
Matrix::returnSomething(matrix);
matrix.returnSomething(martix);
```

Comment: Yes I know that, I just want to protect it from myself or somebody else. When one time I forgot about it and I wrote m.returnSomething(), I would whole day try to find where is the bug

Comment: Let me ask a question, look at the line: `Matrix m2 = m.returnSomething(martix);`. The line is correct, but don't you think it has no sense? For what should I use the `m` object for other Matrix instead of `Matrix m2 = Matrix::returnSomething(matrix)`?

Comment: @Tom That's simply how the language works. If you really want to forbid this, put the static member function elsewhere (a namespace or a different class).

Comment: OK, if there is no other method I just do like you said ;) Thank You